# What does "pch" stand for?

Tags: r

This line of R code

```
plot(1:3,4:6,pch=7:9)
```

produces a plot with three points drawn with different symbols.  What does `pch` stand for?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See `?points`: `pch`: **p**lotting ‘**ch**aracter’

Comment: No, docs are not the best.

Check this line in the R mirror code source: https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/af7f52f70101960861e5d995d3a4bec010bc89e6/src/library/graphics/man/points.Rd#L36